# If $Ref, Imf \in C^1$ at $z_0$, $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Re\Big(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\Big)\in \mathbb{R}$, prove $f$ differentiable at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> If $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is such that $Ref, Imf$ are $C^1$ at $z_0\in A$ and the limit:
>   $$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Re\bigg(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\bigg)$$
>   exists in $\mathbb{R}$, prove that $f$ is differentiable at $z_0.$

*Attempt*. All we need to prove is that 
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Im\bigg(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\bigg)$$
also exists in $\mathbb{R}.$ Writing 
$$\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\frac{u(z)+iv(z)-u(z_0)-iv(z_0)}{x-x_0+i(y-y_0)}$$ didn't get me somewhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related [Limits of Real and Imaginary Parts](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limits_of_Real_and_Imaginary_Parts) ?

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $z_0=f(z_0)=0$. By assumption
$$f(z)= u(x,y)+ i v(x,y)=(ax+by)+i(cx+dy)+o\bigl(|z|\bigr)\quad(z\to0)$$
with $a$, $b$, $c$, $d\in{\mathbb R}$. It follows that
$${f(z)\over z}={f(z)\>\bar z\over|z|^2}={(ax+by)(x-iy)+i(cx+dy)(x-iy)\over|z|^2}+o(1)\quad(z\to0)$$
and therefore
$${\rm Re}{f(z)\over z}={ax^2+dy^2 +(b+c)xy\over x^2+y^2}+o(1)\quad(z\to0)\ .$$
It has been shown many times here that the fraction on the RHS has a limit for $(x,y)\to(0,0)\>$ **iff** $\>a=d$ and $b+c=0$. But this means that $u$ and $v$ together satisfy the CR equations at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Can you explain why one can assume $z_{0} = f(z_{0}) = 0$ without loss of generality?

Comment: @JessicaK: It's because the claim is not about $z_0$ and $f(z_0)$, but only about the increments $z-z_0$ and $f(z)-f(z_0)$ attached at the "working point" $\bigl(z_0, f(z_0)\bigr)$.

Comment: what is your opinion of Petros K's answer? Petros K supposes existence of what we're trying to prove i guess

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=a+bi$

$\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim} \frac{u(z)+i v(z)-u(z_0)-i v(z_0) }{z-z_0}=
\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim}\frac{u(z)-u(z_0)}{z-z_0}+ i(\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim}\frac{ v(z)-(z_0)}{z-z_0})\Rightarrow $

$\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim}\frac{u(z)-u(z_0)}{z-z_0}=a$ and $\underset{z\rightarrow z_0}{lim}\frac{ v(z)-(z_0)}{z-z_0}=b$

Comment: How do you assume that $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists (and therefore you write it as $a+bi$)? The exercise indeed proves that the existence of the real part of this limit guarantees the existence of the limit itself.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout agree with you. 1 - it looks like Petros K is finding the values of $a$ and $b$ assuming $f$ is differentiable? 2 - hey wait, maybe there's like a work backwards thing here? If $f$ is differentiable then $a$ and $b$ are such, sooo...idk i don't think the $a$ and $b$ help show $f$ is differentiable

Comment: You are right it was pretty late when I posted this. I was looking an exercise where $f$ its differentiable, and we need to show that $Imf$ and $Ref$ are also differential and i got confused, but it can work backwards as well so I don't think its wrong since it also says what the values are.