# Prove that $f=u+iv$ is diff. at $z_0$ if $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Re\bigg(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\bigg) \in\mathbb R $ and $Ref, Imf$ are $C^1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Q: If $f:A→C $ is such that $ Ref,Imf $ are $C^1$ at $z_0∈A$ and the limit:
$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Re\bigg(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\bigg) )$
exists in R, prove that $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$.

My attempt:
My first attempt was to prove that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Im\bigg(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\bigg)$ , however, having spent a lot of time on it I don't think that it is possible to prove this.

My second attempt was to prove that the above function satisfies the CR equations. By using the fact that the limit of the real part exists, it is easy to show that $u_x=v_y$ . However, I can't find a way to prove that $u_y=-v_x$.

There is already a post about this problem here: [If $Ref, Imf \in C^1$ at $z_0$, $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}Re\Big(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\Big)\in \mathbb{R}$, prove $f$ differentiable at $z_0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900919/if-ref-imf-in-c1-at-z-0-lim-z-rightarrow-z-0re-big-fracfz-fz-0)

Unfortunately I cannot understand the latter part of the solution provided(after we get the linear approx.) in the above post. If someone can please provide a different solution to this problem or go through the same solution in more detail I would be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac {ax^{2}+dy^{2}+(b+c)xy} {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ exists. The limit through $x=0$ is $d$ and the limit through $y=0$ is $a$. Also the limit through $x=y$ is $\frac {a+d+b+c}2$. So all these limits have to be the same. Hence $a=d$ and $a=\frac {a+a+b+c}2$ which gives $b+c=0$. (Conversely if these conditions hold then $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac {ax^{2}+dy^{2}+(b+c)xy} {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ exists and equals $a$).